# Data sync solution?

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, data-synchronization

For some security issues I'm in an envorinment where third party apps can't access my DB. For this reason I should have some service/tool/script (dunno what yet... i'm open to the best option, still reading to see what I'm gonna do...)
which enables me to generate on a regular basis(daily, weekly, monthly) some csv file with all new/modified records for a certain application.

I should be able to automate this process and also export at any time a new file.
So it should keep track for each application which records he still needs.

Each application will need some data in some other format (csv/xls/sql), also some fields will be needed for some application and some aren't... It should be fairly flexible...

What is the best option for me? Creating some custom tables for each application? Based on that extracting modified data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you best thing here, assuming you have access to the server to let you set this up is to make a small command line program that can do the relativley simple task you need. Languages like pearl are good for this sort of thing I do believe.

once you have that 'tool' made you can schedule it through the OS of the server to run ever set amount of time. Either schedule task for a windows server or a cronjob for a linux server.

You can also (with out having to set up the scheduled task if you don't / can't want to) enable this small command line application to be called via 'CGI' this is a special way of letting applications on the server be executed at will by a web user. If you do enable this though, I suggest you add some sort of locking system so that it can only be run every so often and to stop it being run five times at once.

**EDIT**

You might also want to just look into database replication or adding read only users. This saves a hole lot of arseing around. Try to find a solution that dose not split or duplicate data. You can set up users to only be able to access certain parts of the database system in certain ways, such as SELECT data